# Windows programming.Object creation with empty braces

Tags: c++, windows

In windows programming what is the meaning of this?

```
MSG msg = { };
```

Comment: So why is it tagged with objective-C ?

Comment: What language is this? And are you asking about Windows specific issues (i.e. what MSG is), or about struct initialization in general.

Comment: This is windows programming in c++ using visual studio 2010.I was going through msdn site when i encountered it.

Comment: Please tag the question accordingly

Comment: I would contemplate answering, but not until the question is tagged. As soon as you add the C++ tag, the C++ experts here will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSG is a struct declared in the Windows SDK headers, it stores a Windows message.

The `= { }` part of the statement is an initializer expression, it sets the value of the MSG struct.  Since it contains nothing between the braces, all the members of the struct will be set to 0.  It is a simple way to zero-initialize a variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I never came across such kind of initialization.anyways thanks a ton